# Get the current input text in an event handler

Tags: c#, data-binding, blazor

I am trying to pass the current input text value to the server when the user clicks a button. I have tried the code below, but `YourName` was `null`. Why isn't it updating?

```
<input type="text" bind="@YourName"  maxlength="20" />

<button @onclick="() => { Message = ForecastService.Hello(YourName);}">Click</button>

@code {
    string YourName;
```

I have also tried

```
<input type="text" bind-value-oninput="@YourName"  maxlength="20" />
```

and

```
<input type="text" bind-value-onchange="@YourName"  maxlength="20" />
```

, and none of them worked.

I just created the default Blazor application project and added the code above. I left out the `Hello()` method because it is not important for this question. But anyways, here is the git repository for [the full project source code](https://try.gitea.io/stackoverggarfsdfj324/q2/src/branch/master/BlazorApp2). The changes are in `FetchData.razor`; Run the project and go to "Fetch data".

Comment: Can you post minimum reproducible sample?

Comment: Maybe `YourName` should be a property, not a variable? [Here is an example of that](https://blazor-tutorial.net/two-way-data-binding).

Comment: I added the full source code repository at the end. Please refresh the page and see the updated question. And changing `YourName` to a property had no effect.

Comment: I figured it out. I tried `@bind` (not `bind`) and it worked. I think the examples I had seen were outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `bind-value` with `oninput` event

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    @bind-value="YOUR_VARIABLE" 
    @bind-value:event="oninput" 
    maxlength="20" 
/>
```

Your problem is that you are using `@` wrong.

When you have a property that blazor needs to control, you need to pass it with `@`. `bind` is a variable that blazor needs to control and therefor the correct is `@bind` or `@bind-value`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. The binding will never be updated and no event is fired (oninput).